# Как запретит горизонтальный скролл в сафари?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При адаптации сайта в мобильной версии появился горизонтальный скролл но контент за пределы ширины окна браузера не выходит решил overflow-x: hidden и мета тегом user-scalable = "no" но на сафари это решение не работает
подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему

Comment: Значит на самом деле выходит, просто вы не заметили где

Comment: Покажите пример кода с ошибкой

Comment: Откройте Ваш сайт на сафари, когда будете просматривать мобильную версию, побегайте курсором по вашей вёрстке, Вы должны увидеть блок, который вылезает за контейнер. Если не поможет, то начните удалять блоки один за другим. Начните удалять секции (шапка, блоки на странице, подвал), обычно помогает. В какой-то момент всё вернётся в ширину экрана и вы определите место, которое вылезает за контейнер. Найдя блок, начните удалять внутри него области, увидите какая область больше чем нужно и правьте. Важно проверить всё.